# How does context switch in Rust's green threads work?

Tags: rust

I have a pretty good idea how `Erlang` distributes process time between lightweight processes, or how Scala's Future work.

But I didn't manage to find any explanation how `Rust` solves the same problem.

Where can I find this information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE November 20, 2015**: Rust no longer uses green threading, and hasn't for a long time.

The documentation page for [`green`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/green/) might help. Keep in mind that Rust has just about moved away entirely from a green-threads runtime, so whatever information you do find may be outdated or simply no longer be relevant.

It may be reworked at a later date, but for now the focus is on a native, direct implementation of the host OS's APIs (i.e. native threads), the intent being to get that right before moving on to attempting a green threading implementation.

Comment: The link to documentation is broken.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma Rust hasn't used green threading anymore for a long time.